# Adding special tokens in a text tokenization function or model

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, chatbot, tokenize, encoder

I'm trying to make a chatbot model using **Tensorflow Javascript** and I want to tokenize the text such that I can separate the **context**, the **past messages** and the current **prompt** to output a **reply**. So I was thinking that for the model to work properly it has to know the difference between each data I will input.

But the problem is that I can't figure out a way to add special tokens to my text using tfjs(this is possible in python using beet tokenizer). So I would really appreciate your help on this issue. Looking forward to your reply guys

I checked out the Universal Sentence Encoder, and it works perfectly in tokenizing text, but I'm still struggling with the adding special tokens.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.